# STEP (ISO 10303-21) Unset Attributes

Tags: iso, step

I've been building a parser for STEP-formatted data (specifically the ISO 10303-21 standard), but I've run into a roadblock revolving around a  single character - '$'.

A quick Google search reveals that in STEP, this character denotes an 'unset' value, I interpreted this as an uninitialized value, however I don't know exactly what I should do with it.

For example, take the following definitions:

`#111=AXIS2_PLACEMENT_3D('Circle Axis2P3D',#109,#110,$) ;`
`#109=CARTESIAN_POINT('Axis2P3D Location',(104.14,0.,0.)) ;`
`#110=DIRECTION('Axis2P3D Direction',(1.,-0.,0.)) ;`

To me I cannot see how this would even work, as the reference direction is uninitialized, and therefore an x-axis cannot be derived, meaning that anything using this Axis2Placement would also have undefined data.

Normally when I reach this point, I would just define some sort of default data for the given data-type (Vertices (0,0,0), Directions(1,0,0), etc.), however this doesn't seem to work, because there's the chance that my default direction would cause conflicts with the supplied data.

I have Googled what to do in this scenario, only to come up with nothing.

I also have a PDF for a very similar STEP format (ISO-10303-42), but it too doesn't mention any sort of default data, or provide any more insight in to how this works.

So, to explicitly state my question: what do I do with uninitialized data in STEP (ISO 10303-21) data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be able to represent 'unset' as a distinct value. It doesn't mean the same thing as an uninitialized value or a default value. For example you might represent `AXIS2_PLACEMENT_3D` as an object with data members that are pointers to point to `CARTESIAN_POINT` and `DIRECTION`, and the `$` means that that pointer will be null in your representation.

Dealing with null values will depend on the context. It may be some kind of error if the data is really necessary. Or it may be that the data isn't necessary, such as if you don't need the axis to be oriented, and a point and direction are sufficient to represent the data.

Answer (score 0):

When `$` sign is used , the value is not required. Specifically, if there are a series of optional values and you want to specify a value for, let's say, 3rd optional argument and you don't want to specify values for the 1st and 2nd optional arguments, you can use `$` sign for those two.

Take a look [here](http://www.steptools.com/library/standard/p21e3_dis_preview.html#clause-13-2-2) for a better description.

Answer (score 0):

In this case: #111 is local coordinate system with following 4 attributes:

- character name;
- pointer to origin (#109);
- pointer to axis (#110);
- pointer to second axis (reference direction).

If #111 is a coordinate system of circle (I guess it with 'name' value), axis is normal of circle plane, while reference direction points to start of circle (position of zero t parameter of circle). Since a circle is closed curve, you can locate this zero t position in arbitrary place, it has no influence on circle geometric shape, reference direction in this case is not mandatory, and is omitted. And it is your choice how you handle this situation.